# VB Script to Refresh Excel

Tags: excel, vbscript

I'm trying to piece together / learn VB to create a real simple script to open a excel document, based on a file path I specify, refresh the external data connections. 
Then wait until the refresh is done, then save the file in the same location, then  quit excel.

What I have so far, seems to work other than that when it saves the file, it saves it to a different location, and does not overwrite the existing file!

This is my first use of VB, I am booked to go on a course for this in a few months time, but I wanted to experiment a bit first, by grabbing bit of code from google and this site :)

Sorry If this is an easy question, but to me it is quite challenging!!

Here's what I have so far....

```
Dim oExcel
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 

oExcel.Visible = True
oExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
oExcel.AskToUpdateLinks = False
oExcel.AlertBeforeOverwriting = False

Set oWorkbook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open("The File Path of my .xlsx File")
oWorkbook.RefreshAll
oWorkbook.Save

oExcel.Quit
Set oWorkbook = Nothing
Set oExcel = Nothing
```

What I want to happen is, Open the excel file from the location named, update external data, save the file, overwriting the original. Close Excel.

Thanks ever so much
John.

Comment: That is not VB.NET code; VB.NET <> vba AndAlso VB.NET <> vbscript

Comment: You say it "saves to a different location". Where exactly is it saving it? Excel's not going to randomly choose a new name for your workbook, so what type of name are you seeing?

Comment: @Bond The file runs from a network location on my network, with a file mapping of O:\File Path etc, then when it saves it saves to C:\My Documents. It saves with the correct file name, just not the right file path if that makes sense.

Comment: Are you sure the script has permissions to save to that network share and folder? Try using your script on a local Excel file and see if it works.

Comment: @Bond I as a domain user have rights over the network share, but I guess the script doesn't? Hence why it is dumping the file to a local directory. Is there any way I can set it to run as me?

Comment: That's what I'm wondering. If you copy the file to a local folder and run your script, does it work there?

Comment: @Bond Hi, Yes it does work correctly if I save it directly to my local C: file, even drilled down by a couple of extra directories. So it would appear the issue is down to copying to a network location. I either need to know how to make it work in a network location, or how to copy and replace the file after the refresh / save has complete.

Comment: If you're launching the script yourself, it should use your credentials. You can verify this by opening the Processes tab in Task Manager and seeing what name appears next to the `wscript.exe` (or `cscript.exe`) process while your script is executing. If your script is being launched from Task Scheduler or some other means, it may be using an account other than yours.

Answer (score -1):

Try the below

```
oWorkbook.RefreshAll 'Refresh everything
DoEvents 'Let Excel finish
oWorkbook.Close true 'Close the workbook true for save.
```

Comment: When I added your comments I got an error that I don't understand.
Line 11
Char 1
"type mistmatch :'DoEvents'
Code 800A000D

Comment: try oWorkbook.doevents

Comment: Still not having it! , gives me a "object does not support this property or method" error relating to oworkbook.doevent

Comment: If I remvove that line entirely, I get "Unable to set the close property of the workbook class" Which is looking at the line oWorkbook.close = True